# Facebook callback to ngrok.io is not getting through

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm trying to set up a webhook callback to my local machine as I've done a hundred times before. Has someone the same problems getting the call through? I can access my ngrok endpoint from my cellphone so the problem shouldn't be on ngrok's side.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the us region has a problem.
Starting ngrok like: ngrok http -region eu 3000 did it for me.

Comment: I tried with all locations (au, eu, us) however still only FB can't reach it

Comment: Try using a proper server(with a static IP).

Comment: try serveo.net, it works. Maybe there's just some errors sometime if your hosting's internet provider is not a fast one

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: @JimwelAnobong 's suggestions worked for me. Issue with Ngrok